# Passing shell variable to SQL*Plus create statment

Tags: oracle, shell, sqlplus

I am trying to pass a shell variable to SQL*Plus, to be used as a substitution variable in a `create tablespace` statement in a script.

```sh
sqlplus -s -l shiyas/******** @/path/schema_creation_script.sql "$DEST_SCH" <<EOF
EOF
```

The tablespace creation script inside the above mentioned .sql file is

```sql
CREATE TABLESPACE &1 DATAFILE '/data1/data/mcpod/&1_01.dbf'
SIZE 104864 k AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 10240 K FLASHBACK off;
```

The create tablespace was failing. I tried with below statement inside the create tablespace script:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE &1 DATAFILE '/data1/data/mcpod/"&1"_01.dbf'
SIZE 104864 k AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 10240 K FLASHBACK off;
```

The tablspace and datafile were created. But the datafile was created with double quotes.

```
/data1/data/mcpod/"C_40050"_01.dbf
```

How I can pass the shell variable and create the tablespace without having to have double quotes in the datafule name?

Answer (score 0):

You need to terminate the substitution variable with a period:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE &1 DATAFILE '/data1/data/mcpod/&1._01.dbf' SIZE 104864 k AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 10240 K FLASHBACK off;
                                                   ^
```

[The documentation says](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#sthref458):

> If you wish to append characters immediately after a substitution variable, use a period to separate the variable from the character. For example:
>
> ```
> SELECT SALARY FROM EMP_DETAILS_VIEW WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID='&X.5';
> Enter value for X:  20
> ```
>
> is interpreted as
>
> ```
> SELECT SALARY FROM EMP_DETAILS_VIEW WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID='205';
> ```

You are doing something similar. In your original code `&1_01.dbf` is interpreted as a single substitution variable called `1_01`; the period terminates that; and then `dbf` is appended.

You aren't providing a value for a variable called `1_01`, so it will prompt for that. Your shell script won't do this, but if you responded to that prompt again with the same value `C_40050`, the final datafile argument for the `create` would be `'/data1/data/mcpod/C_40050dbf'`, with no period before the `dbf`.

With the addition of the terminating period to make it `&1._01.dbf` your existing argument will still be used as a positional substitution value, so the datafile argument will be `'/data1/data/mcpod/C_40050_01.dbf'` - only the `&1_01.` part is replaced.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The termination using the '.' worked fine. Issue is resolved. Thanks a lot for the support.